# Multiple Pixelsearch

Tags: loops, if-statement, autohotkey

Question about some code i wrote...

Its alltime starting at the first step.... not checking if the pixel was found.

I want a code like this:

If Pixelsearch(wasfound)
Do, Step1
if Pixelsearch(wasfound)
Do, Step2

it should search for multiple pixel and only do the step who i wrote for that pixel...

but it start alltime at step1

```
if PixelSearch (X, Y, 255, 160, 275, 180, 0x609661, 1, Fast)
GoTo, Step1do

else
if PixelSearch (X, Y, 47, 156, 68, 175, 0x065D25, 1, Fast)
GoTo, Step2do

else
if PixelSearch (X, Y, 118, 333, 147, 361, 0x387140, 1, Fast)
GoTo, Step3do

else
if PixelSearch (X, Y, 240, 277, 280, 313, 0x2F6837, 1, Fast)
GoTo, Step4do

else
if PixelSearch (X, Y, 10, 255, 30, 280, 0x4A8454, 1, Fast)
GoTo, Step5do

else
if PixelSearch (X, Y, 275, 185, 310, 210, 0x366E3E, 1, Fast)
GoTo, Step6do

else
RandSleep(1000,2000)
```

Comment: hmm... no one can answer me?

Comment: Please share the rest of the source, also you should avoid Goto (use gosub instead) when possible.